# Custom camera with a button

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-camera

I want to create a camera app using xamarin which should have custom button as shown in below pic, to do other processing using that button as shown in below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS9ct.png)

i have created the app and Source code is placed in below link:
https://github.com/waseefur/CustomCamera-Resolution.git

This Camera has been displayed through the **TextureView**, but the camera has very low resolution of picture, can anyone advice me how to improve the camera resolution.

or is it possible to create custom buttom as shown in above image by using **MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync()**

Comment: You can try using Xamarin Community Toolkit [Camera View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/cameraview). Here's the documentation, there are also samples for it

Comment: This link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50767653/need-a-way-to-add-a-button-to-this-android-xamarin-sample) may help you.